# pointer to pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

I need help with pointers in C. I've two structures a struct made like this:

```
    typedef struct s{
        s2** d;
        struct s* next;
    }s;


 typedef struct s2{
        c* fi;
        struct s2* next;
    }s2;
```

And I have a function like this one:

```
void modify(c* a, s2* b){   //c* is a pointer to a struct
    s* rd = malloc(sizeof(s);
    rd->next = NULL;
    //need also to initialize the field "d" of the "s" struct
}
```

This is generating error. I need the structure rd to point to b as in the example. I need to store a double pointer because s2 are linked in list-like fashion, so I need the ** pointer to have the possibility to remove the first element of the list. I was doing the assignment in the comment like rd->d = &b but when I try to deference the field "d" in a function I have an invalid memory read and I can't understand why.

Comment: Could you explain why you need a double pointer on the 'd' type? It isn't obvious at all from your description.

Comment: what is d in struct s? Why are you trying to assign a s2* to a d**?

Comment: @Ptival: Sorry, It was s2**, I made a mistake trying to semplify things to let you understand the question. 
@jv42: because the s2 is stored inside another struct (like s2*) and I need to be able to set this pointer to NULL. I know this is quite complicated..

Comment: Is this for the International Obfuscated C Code Contest?

Comment: @spookyjon: no, but maybe I should partecipate :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the problem is this:

You pass in `s2* b` as an argument to `modify`, thus this pointer resides on the stack. Now when you assign `rd->d = &b`, you take that location on the stack, which will only be valid until execution leaves the scope of `modify`. Thus, when you dereference `rd->d` later on, you access that (now invalid) location on the stack, which yields garbage or a crash. (However, in this scenario, you should be able to dereference `rd->d` correctly while still in `modify`.)

Probably you'd want to alter how `b` is passed into modify, most likely into something like `s2** b`, so that you can correctly pass in a pointer to a pointer to `s2` in another structure, instead of making it a pointer to `s2` sitting on the stack for `modify`.

Basically like this:

```
void modify(c* a, s2** b) {
    s* rd = malloc(sizeof(s));
    rd->next = NULL;
    rd->d = b;
}
```

and call it like

```
s2* myS2 = ...;
modify(<whatever>, &myS2->next);
```

This should allow you to pass the location of a pointer to a `s2` instance which you can store away and dereference even after `modify` finishes (untested, though).